# How to concatenate correctly in PHP

Tags: php, string, concatenation, var

I have this next code and it doesn't print the value for the var `$item`. how do i make it return the value of item.

```
<?php
$item = "wewewe";
$plu = $_POST[‘plu’];
$img = $_POST[‘img’];
$password = $_POST[‘password’];

echo '<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>'.$item.' </td>
  <td>666</td>
  <td> <img src="apple.jpg" alt=""> </td>
</tr>'
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$item = "wewewe";
$plu = (isset($_POST['plu']))?$_POST['plu']:'';
$img = (isset($_POST['img']))?$_POST['img']:'';
$password = (isset($_POST['password']))?$_POST['password']:'';
?>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><?= $item ?></td>
  <td>666</td>
  <td> <img src="apple.jpg" alt=""> </td>
</tr>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It doesn't work, It doesnt print the $item value, and I would like to echo the value as in my example.

Comment: @miguel munoz i just tested out, it works
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/56042faf3d1f4188c7922269c69dc6d742c9c769, show full page, what you trying to do.

Comment: sorry about that. if I put my code as I posted it in the question it works in that website but not on my IDE, I guess the problem is not the concatenation

Comment: Yes, it may be the problem with localhost, check if all services required are running.

Answer (score 0):

In php, if you want to print a value or a variable you have to use the "echo" keyword.

Try this :

```
<?php echo '
<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
 <td> '.$item.' </td>
 <td>666</td>
 <td> <img src="apple.jpg" alt=""> </td>
</tr>'; ?>
```